# Bet settling function in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that takes a sports bet and returns its Net result.

If you are not familiar with betting, an exhaustive test suite should help with understanding what the program is supposed to do. How can I solve this problem in a way distinct from enumerating all of the possible cases?

```
SUPPORTED_BET_TYPES = ['total', 'handicap']
SIDES = ['home', 'away', 'over', 'under']
BET_OUTCOMES = ['Won', 'Lost', 'Cancelled', 'Half Won', 'Half Lost']


def settle_bet(bet_type, side, points, price, bet_amount, home_score, away_score):
    '''Returns a result of the bet'''

    if bet_type == 'total':
        return settle_total_bet(side, points, price, bet_amount, home_score, away_score)
    elif bet_type == 'handicap':
        return settle_handicap_bet(side, points, price, bet_amount, home_score, away_score)


def settle_total_bet(side, points, price, bet_amount, home_score, away_score):
    '''Returns Net result of the bet on total'''
    outcome = determine_total_bet_outcome(side, points, home_score, away_score)

    if outcome == 'Won':
        return bet_amount * (price - 1)
    elif outcome == 'Half Won':
        return bet_amount * ((price - 1) / 2)
    elif outcome == 'Cancelled':
        return 0
    elif outcome == 'Half Lost':
        return bet_amount * (-1 / 2)
    else:
        return bet_amount * -1


def determine_total_bet_outcome(side, points, home_score, away_score):
    '''Returns the appropriate outcome of the bet from BET_OUTCOMES'''
    total_score = home_score + away_score
    points_score_diff = points - total_score

    if points_score_diff == 0:
        return 'Cancelled'
    elif points_score_diff == 0.25:
        if side == 'over':
            return 'Half Lost'
        else:
            return 'Half Won'
    elif points_score_diff == -0.25:
        if side == 'over':
            return 'Half Won'
        else:
            return 'Half Lost'
    elif points_score_diff >= 0.5:
        if side == 'over':
            return 'Lost'
        else:
            return 'Won'
    elif points_score_diff <= -0.5:
        if side == 'over':
            return 'Won'
        else:
            return 'Lost'


def test():
    # Bets on Total

    # Won or Lost
    assert settle_bet('total', 'over', 2.5, 1.90, 100, 3, 2) == 100 * (1.90 - 1)
    assert settle_bet('total', 'over', 3.5, 1.85, 100, 0, 1) == 100 * -1
    assert settle_bet('total', 'under', 2.5, 1.94, 100, 0, 0) == 100 * (1.94 - 1)
    assert settle_bet('total', 'under', 3.5, 1.75, 100, 1, 3) == 100 * -1

    # Won or Lost Or Cancelled
    assert settle_bet('total', 'over', 3.0, 1.82, 100, 2, 2) == 100 * (1.82 - 1)
    assert settle_bet('total', 'over', 3.0, 1.82, 100, 1, 2) == 100 * 0
    assert settle_bet('total', 'over', 3.0, 1.82, 100, 0, 0) == 100 * -1

    assert settle_bet('total', 'under', 3.0, 1.82, 100, 2, 2) == 100 * -1
    assert settle_bet('total', 'under', 3.0, 1.82, 100, 1, 2) == 100 * 0
    assert settle_bet('total', 'under', 3.0, 1.82, 100, 0, 0) == 100 * (1.82 - 1)

    # Won or Lost or Half Won or Half Lost
    assert settle_bet('total', 'over', 2.25, 1.95, 100, 2, 1) == 100 * (1.95 - 1)
    assert settle_bet('total', 'over', 2.25, 1.90, 100, 0, 0) == 100 * -1
    assert settle_bet('total', 'over', 2.25, 1.80, 100, 1, 1) == 100 * (-1 / 2)

    assert settle_bet('total', 'under', 2.25, 1.95, 100, 2, 1) == 100 * -1
    assert settle_bet('total', 'under', 2.25, 1.90, 100, 0, 0) == 100 * (1.90 - 1)
    assert settle_bet('total', 'under', 2.25, 1.80, 100, 1, 1) == 100 * ((1.80 - 1) / 2)

    assert settle_bet('total', 'over', 2.75, 1.90, 100, 3, 3) == 100 * (1.90 - 1)
    assert settle_bet('total', 'over', 2.75, 1.88, 100, 1, 2) == 100 * ((1.88 - 1) / 2)
    assert settle_bet('total', 'over', 2.75, 1.90, 100, 1, 0) == 100 * -1

    assert settle_bet('total', 'under', 2.75, 1.90, 100, 3, 3) == 100 * -1
    assert settle_bet('total', 'under', 2.75, 1.88, 100, 1, 2) == 100 * (-1 / 2)
    assert settle_bet('total', 'under', 2.75, 1.90, 100, 1, 0) == 100 * (1.90 - 1)

    print("All tests passed.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: Your question is off-topic here, because we require code to be completely working (to the best of the authors knowledge), before we review it. You can ask these kind of questions on stackoverflow.com

Comment: The code is working! The tests pass. That's funny, that I asked the same question on stackoverlow and some user suggested that it should have been asken on codereview! Please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61951015/how-to-write-a-bet-settling-function-in-python

Comment: "I couldn't finish settling bets on handicap since it led to some enormous wall of nested if/else statements". That doesn't sound like the code is working. If your code really is working completely, I suggest to edit your question. That will help to prevent misunderstandings.

Comment: I had deleted unfinished part before posting and posted a complete working program (though without a part that I had initially intended to do) so that formally everything is ok.

Comment: The problem is that you are writing about a part of the code that you couldn't complete yet, so most people probably won't even read the rest of your question here, because they think it is off-topic. I highly suggest to delete this part. It will help your question to get more attention.

Comment: Fine, I have deleted that part. Feel free to go ahead :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem appears to be a [poster child](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poster_child) for basic object-oriented programming. But please note that I don't know anything about sports betting, so I'll probably get some of the details wrong.

A good rule of thumb is this: If you find yourself switching on internal data, look for a class instead.

In your case, you switch on `bet_type`, you switch on `outcome`, you switch on `side`, and you switch on `points_scored_diff`. I'm willing to  ... bet ... that there are some class behaviors to be found in all that.

Since you aren't using classes in your code, I'm going to assume you might not be familiar with them. So I'll keep this as straightforward as possible. (If you are doing this for homework and forbidden to use classes, you should have mentioned that -- some of this could be tuples with lambdas.

```
class WagerOutcome:
    """ Base class for wager outcomes.
    """
    def __init__(self, name, price):
        self.price = price
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

class TotalWagerWon(WagerOutcome):
    def __init__(self, price):
        super().__init__("Won", price)

    def payout(self, bet_amount: float) -> float:
        return bet_amount * (self.price - 1)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        """ Stringify this object. Because the price affects the payout for this 
            outcome, I am including price in the display.
        """
        return f"{self.name}({self.price})"
```

You can figure out the rest, I suspect.

With outcomes now a class, let's turn to the bet types. You didn't include any examples of handicap bets, which is unfortunate. Other than simple point handicaps, I can't imagine what else there would be. So I'm ignoring handicap types.

```
class Wager:
    """ Base class for all wager types.
    """
    def __init__(self, *, type: str, side: str, points: SupportsFloat = None, price: SupportsFloat, amount: SupportsFloat):
        self.type = type
        self.side = side
        self.points = float(points)
        self.price = float(price)
        self.amount = float(amount)

class WagerTotalHome(Wager):
    """ Total wager on home team.
    """
    def __init__(self, *, price: SupportsFloat, amount: SupportsFloat, points: int = None):
        super().__init__(type='total', side='home', price=price, amount=amount, points=points)

    def get_outcome(self, home_points, away_points):
        """ Determine outcome by points scored. Return a WagerOutcome.
        """
        if home_points > away_points:
            return TotalWagerWon(self.price)
        else:
            return TotalWagerLost(self.price)
```

Now I can write a factory function that maps the strings into types:

```
def make_wager(type, side, points, price, amount) -> Wager:
    """ Construct and return Wager objects of a type determined by the arguments.
    """
    wager_classes = {
        ('total', 'home'): WagerTotalHome,
        ('total', 'away'): WagerTotalAway,
        ('total', 'over'): WagerTotalOver,
        ('total', 'under'): WagerTotalUnder,
    }

    klass = wager_classes[(type, side)]
    wager = klass(points=points, price=price, amount=amount)
    return wager
```

Then I can say:

```
bet = make_wager('total', 'home', price=2, amount=100)
outcome = bet.get_outcome(3, 0)
payout = outcome.payout(bet.amount)
```

That last bit is a little shaky: I really shouldn't have to feed in the `bet.amount` if the `outcome` is returned by the `bet`. But I'm not clear where your trouble with handicap bets lies, so I left things loose.

The point, really, is that using objects/classes, I can move the "wall of if/else" statements into a collection of discrete behaviors. Once we know the bet type is "WagerTotalHome", there is no more need for if/else statements involving the type or the side. All that remains is to determine the outcome of the wager and return that.

Knowing the outcome, there is no need for if/else statements about anything. Simply encode the computation of the payout using the price and bet amount, and return that.

The one remaining bit of complexity is mapping input strings  (or dropdown menu items or whatever) onto wager classes. The factory function uses a dictionary of tuples for that,  so it's not as bad as it might first seem.

Comment: First of all, thanks for taking time to write such a detailed review!  
Let's start with `Outcome` classes and in order to keep things simple lets ignore handicap bets for now and focus on totals, I have tried to go on on your suggestion and create a class for all of the 5 possible outcomes, here is my code:  
 https://pastebin.com/DQnr19cU  
As far as `Wager` class is concerned I don't understand what `*` parameter means in `__init__` method and why `points` parameter has an `int` type whereas it can be 2.5 or 3.25.  
Regarding to `make_wager()`: is it a stand-alone function?

Comment: The `*` [froces named args](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14298976/4029014). `points`  was `int` because I don't know sports betting -- I'll edit it to `float`. Yes, `make_wager` is an example of a factory function. You could also use a *factory method* on a base class, if you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

### Tests

You've written some - great! Keep that up. If you want to add more structure, consider Python's `unittest` library.

### Unused globals

`BET_OUTCOMES`, `SUPPORTED_BET_TYPES` and `SIDES` are not used. My assumption is that this is related to the other segment of your code that you deleted. If it stays deleted, then delete these, too.

Similarly, this docstring:

```
'''Returns the appropriate outcome of the bet from BET_OUTCOMES'''
```

is now incorrect.

### Stringly-typed variables

`bet_type` being either `total` or `handicap` should not be represented as a string. It should be represented as an `Enum`, or maybe if there will remain only two states, a boolean such as `is_handicap_bet`. The same applies to `outcome`.

### Negation

`bet_amount * -1` should be `-bet_amount`. 
`bet_amount * (-1 / 2)` should be `-bet_amount / 2`.

Comment: Thanks for you review!
Globals are provided for readers which are not familiar with gambling rather than to be used in the code itself.

The docstring should be fine because the function returns only the values listed in BET_OUTCOMES.

Agree that stringly-typed variables could be replaced with enum. Enum seems more suitable than boolean because it allows to add other bet types such as "individual total" or "to qualify".

Negation in tests is used in order to show how the result is obtained.